# -su: sudo : No such file or directory

Tags: sudo

```
-su: export: `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/usr/local/hadoop/bin': not a valid identifier
hadoopmaster@dhruv-Inspiron-N5010:~$ sudo gedit ~/.bashrc
-su: sudo: No such file or directory
hadoopmaster@dhruv-Inspiron-N5010:~$ clear
-su: clear: No such file or directory
hadoopmaster@dhruv-Inspiron-N5010:~$ cler
-su: cler: No such file or directory
hadoopmaster@dhruv-Inspiron-N5010:~$ clear
-su: clear: No such file or directory
hadoopmaster@dhruv-Inspiron-N5010:~$ sudo
-su: sudo: No such file or directory
hadoopmaster@dhruv-Inspiron-N5010:~$ sudo gedit ~/.bashrc
-su: sudo: No such file or directory
hadoopmaster@dhruv-Inspiron-N5010:~$ clear
-su: clear: No such file or directory
```

Comment: It's unclear what your asking here. Please edit your question to make this clear. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm not able to use the clear command or any command such as sudo gedit ~/.bashrc ...It shows no such file or directory

Comment: You should edit your question to add this information

Comment: dhruv@dhruv-Inspiron-N5010:~$ su - hadoopmaster
Password: 
-su: export: `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/usr/local/hadoop/bin': not a valid identifier
 why it is showing not a valid identifier ?

Comment: are you trying to export your $PATH variable? show us the output from sudo -i

Comment: hadoopmaster@dhruv-Inspiron-N5010:~$ sudo -i -
-su: sudo: No such file or directory
hadoopmaster@dhruv-Inspiron-N5010:~$ sudo -i
-su: sudo: No such file or directory

Comment: Yes...I'm exporting $PATH